# how to use date as dummy variable for multiple date range?

Tags: python, date, pyspark, regression, mean

I am working on pandas dataframe and I need to use multi-variate regression analysis. The independent variable that I am using is date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. So far I have understood that I can use dummy variables for date.

The scenario is as described below:

- The dates in the dataset are from `2017-08-18 to 2019-08-12`
- I need to calculate `count` of `products` for all the dates
- Now I need to check the `mean` of `products` for multiple dates and respective date range, i.e, if I take `2017-09-21` then I need to calculate mean of `products` `7 days before` and `7 days after` `2017-09-21`.
- Now I have `mean_products_before (2017-09-15 , 2017-09-16, 2017-09-17, ..., 2017-09-21)`and `mean_products_after(2017-09-21, 2017-09-22, 2017-09-23, ..., 2017-09-28)`
- Now I do not have just one date but multiple dates where I need to compute the mean: `017-09-21, 2017-09-28, 2017-10-17, 2017-11-26, 2017-12-09, and few more`
- The question is can I use dummy variables in this scenario? Is it even possible or I do it some other better way? The aim is find if date (independent variable) has an effect or relationship with `mean_products_before` and `mean_products_after` which are both dependent variables.

I apologize if anything is not clear. Please feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: you have dates in range of 7 days, not continuously like 2017-08-18, 2017-08-19, 2017-08-20... right? bcz its bit confusing, keep some raw sample data. and expected output so that it would be easy to arrive at answer.

Comment: the dates in the range is continuous. please check the edited question. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the way you can make use of date values to get dummies.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import pandas as pd

_date = datetime.fromisoformat('2017-08-18')
dateList=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    _date += timedelta(days=1)
    dateList.append(_date.date().isoformat())

pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(dateList))
```

output would be.

```
            2017-08-19  2017-08-20  2017-08-21  2017-08-22  2017-08-23  2017-08-24  2017-08-25  2017-08-26  2017-08-27  2017-08-28
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: thank you for looking into it. but your solution adds 7 days to the given date whereas if the given date is 2017-09-21 then I meant all 7 days before: 2017-09-14, 2017-09-15 , 2017-09-16, 2017-09-17, 2017-09-18, 2017-09-19, 2017-09-20.

Comment: Updated for one day, But it is just the way of making use of daterange for getting dummies. maynot be what you are expecting.